# file permissions security apache

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, unix

I'm trying to figure out the best file permissions/user/groups for files under my document root? I have the following file structure with `/home/user/public_html` holding all my php files and directories. Inside that, I have one directory `/home/user/public_html/files/`where people upload images to.

What is the most secure way to distribute file permissions/groups/user so that apache can properly display the php files and directories?

Should I make `public_html` owned by apache? What group should I use for `public_html`?

Answer (score 1):

Is this server used by any others, or just yourself (ie. is it dedicated or shared).

Generally, best practice is `rwx` for the owner and read-only for anyone else. If you are running PHP as mod_php (without a custom Apache build, eg. mpm-per-child), then you'll want www-data/apache (whoever Apache is running as) to have full `rwx` access, the FTP/SSH user will also need `rwx` access.

So its likely to make the owner your FTP/SSH user with `rwx`, the group the Apache user with `rwx` and just read-only or nothing at all to everyone else.

Eg. 774 or 770

Again, if your FTP/SSH user is not the same as your PHP/Apache user then you'll want to make sure your file permissions stay as they should be, even when each respective user creates new files.

```
ftpuser=""
apacheuser=""
chown -R ftpuser:apacheuser /home/$ftpuser/public_html
chmod -R 775 /home/$ftpuser/public_html
setfacl -d -m u::rwX,g::rwX,o::rx /home/$ftpuser/public_html
chmod g+s /home/$ftpuser/public_html
```

To use the above commands, you'll need to make sure that you enable ACLs for your active partition, see http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/ACL/linux-acl.html

But it would be preferred to use PHP-FPM, then you can run the PHP instance as a specific user (and more), and no more permissions headaches.